# Retrieves only 5 elements from rabbitmq queue

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have 10 messages in the queue.
Is there a way to consume only 5 messages out of 10 messages?
I am working with nodejs.

This is my source code:

```
consumer.js
```

```
const consumer = async ({routeKey}) => {
const fastify = Fastify({
  logger: true
})

await fastify.register(fastifyAmqp, {
  protocol: 'amqp',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5672,
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'admin',
})

const channel = await fastify.amqp.channel;

const queue = 'users'

channel.assertQueue(queue, {
  durable: true,
})

await channel.consume(q.queue, function (msg) {
  if (msg.content) {
    JSON.parse(msg.content.toString())
  }
}, {
  noAck: false
});}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.